# Estimating the Size of an Approximating Polyline

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, approximation-theory

let $\gamma(s) = \left(x(s),y(s)\right), s\in[0,1]; \gamma'(s) = 1$ be a length-parameterized curve in the plane, with finite and strictly positive curvature.

> Questions:
>
> - is it possible to estimate the minimal number of vertices of an approximating polyline (with vertices on the curve), for which the maximal distance of its segments to the curve is bound by some constant $c$?
> - does the following formula yield such an estimate $$1+\frac{1}{\int_0^1\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}2*\arccos(1-\kappa(s)*c)ds }, $$ where $\kappa(s)>0$ denotes the curvature?

The denominator in the formula is intended to represent the average length of the portion of the curve between two adjacent vertices of the polyline. Taking the reciprocal of that average should yield an estimate for the number edges in the polyline.

Comment: You should certainly be more careful with the curvature formula because if you have a tiny nearly straight piece on your curve, the integral in the denominator will blow up ($\arccos(1-t)\approx \sqrt t$, so it won't cancel the denominator).

Comment: @fedja thanks for pointing me to the flaw; I fixed it in an edit.

Comment: I'm not sure you did: a nearly straight piece is still a clear trouble. You are fine in the regime $\kappa\ge \kappa_0>0, c\to 0$ but not in the regime $c=const, \inf\kappa\to 0$.

Comment: @fedja I am aware of that problem and my admittedly sloppy formulation of "strictly positive" was meant to exclude the problematic case. But I wonder if it can occur if the curve is continuous and defined over a closed interval.

Answer (score 4):

*Polygonal curve simplification* is a well-studied topic. Here is one
paper that gives a pretty good summary of previous work on exactly optimal algorithms, as well as contributing to approximation algorithms:

> Agarwal, P. K., Har-Peled, S., Mustafa, N. H., & Wang, Y. (2005). Near-linear time approximation algorithms for curve simplification. *Algorithmica*, 42(3-4), 203-219. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00453-005-1165-y).)

In summary: Achieving the minimal number of vertices for a given error $\epsilon$ seems to take near-quadratic time, but approximations to the minimal number can be achieved in near-linear time.

Viewing curve simplification in terms of curvature is less explored, but here
is one paper:

> Chuon, C., Guha, S., Janecek, P., & Song, N. D. C. (2011). Simplipoly: Curvature-based polygonal curve simplification. *International Journal of Computational Geometry & Applications*, 21(04), 417-429.
>   ([Journal link](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218195911003743).)

Comment: The pointers to the articles are helpful for practical calculations, but what I am looking for, is an expression based on differential-geometric properties.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Thanks for clarifying.